# How to prevent Initialize Macro in Excel from clearing data I need to save

Tags: excel, vba

Update macro writes data from "Input" worksheet to "Orders" worksheet. I want to initialize data on Input sheet but it also clears data written to Orders sheet.
Any help will be appreciated.
Update Macro:

```
Sheets("Orders").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Input!R17C7"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Input!R17C9"
```

Initialize Macro: clears data in both sheets

```
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("G17").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("I17").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the `.Select` & `.Selection` method when possible. Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for more information on that.

Notice how you can skip those lines and jump right to the conclusion:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Orders").Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "Input!R17C7"
Thisworkbook.SHeets("Orders").Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "Input!R17C9"
```

&

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("G17:I17").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

Write only these two lines

```
Sheets("Input").Range("G17").ClearContents
Sheets("Input").Range("I17").ClearContents
```

to clear the contents in `G17` and `I17` of "Input".